# Sometimes when slickgrid is updated the updates don't display

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

When I update some values in my Slickgrid sometimes I need to reload the entire grid. I've checked that the correct data is returned, and it is, but the slickgrid itself does not get updated. If I click on cells with an editor then their values update, but it's only when I reload the slickgrid again that everything updates.

The code to load the grid and to load it after updates is the same, or does the issue come from the data being very similar, so it won't do a refresh?

I use this function to render the grid after I get the data from an ajax call and determine which columns to display:

```
    // render the grid with the given columns and data
    var renderGrid = function(columns, data) {
        grid.setColumns(columns);
        dataView.beginUpdate();
        dataView.setItems(data);
        dataView.endUpdate();
        grid.setSelectedRows([]);
        grid.render();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different question, but using the grid update functions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21276322/4606828) answer, I got it working.

Comment: The key take-away is `grid.invalidate()`. See also the discussion found in the [getting started](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Getting-Started). Side note, the explicit call to `dataview.refresh` in the linked answer is extraneous as it is called from `dataview.endUpdate`.

Comment: Yes, I was struggling to get an example on the slickgrid site of rendering with dataView. Thanks for your help.